# Jquery Dialog is always transparent

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-dialog

My jquery dialog is transparent for some reason but it does show the fields for the partial view that I am loading. I'm not sure why it's doing this when I have another jquery dialog working fine.

```
            @Html.ActionLink("Upload Image", "UploadImage", "Patients", null, new { @class = "popupLinks" })
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $(".popupLinks").click(function (e) {
                        var url = this.href;                        
                        $("#imageUpload").load(url,{},function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                            $("#imageUpload").dialog({
                                modal: true,
                                autoOpen: true,
                                draggable: true,
                                resizable: false,
                                width: 500,
                                show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 2000 },
                                    close: function (event, ui) {
                                        dialog.remove();
                                    }                                    
                            }).dialog("widget").next(".ui-widget-overlay").css("background", "#000000");;
                            }
                        );
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue.

In addition to `jquery.ui.dialog.css`, you need to include the link to the base jQuery UI CSS: `jquery-ui.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it uses images for the background of the dialog.  In your jQuery installation for this project, did you remember the `/themes/base/images` folders?

Answer (score 0):

This has been superseded. Now when jQuery UI package is added, all css files are downloaded to the /content/themes/base folder. You will also note a file called "all.css" that imports css files. Add a link as follows:

`<link href="content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />`